# randomly replace rows by other rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

First, it reads the data from file and transpose. Everything is fine here.

Next, it generates two random samples r1 and r2. Everything is fine here.

Last, it generates a matrix with the same shape as data, and use for loop to loop r1 and r2 simultaneously, then replace row j by data[j,:] + data[i,:]. (using print(sum(data[j,:] + data[i,:]), sum(r_data[j,:])) to check if it works). Everything is fine till now.

But finally, when I check r_data, all the elements are 0. I don't why, did I make any mistakes? Appreciate for you help!!!

PS, I tried replacing data by data = np.ones((n,k)), and it works. I really have no idea how this bug happens. It only happens when I read the data from file.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("nonames.txt")
data = np.transpose(data)
n = len(data[:,0])
k = len(data[0,:])

# randomly merging samples
c =  np.arange(n)
r1 = np.random.choice(c, 500, replace=False)
r2 = np.random.choice(c, 500, replace=False)
r_data = np.zeros((n,k))
for i,j in zip(r1,r2):
    r_data[j,:] = data[j,:] + data[i,:]
    print(sum(data[j,:] + data[i,:]), sum(r_data[j,:]))
```

Comment: can you add the array `data` to your question

Comment: @djk47463 Sorry I can't, I don't have the permission, but it is just a text file with integers 0 to 100

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when using `a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000,500))` followed by `np.savetxt("nonames.txt", a, fmt='%i')` as an example file. Using `np.random.seed(42)`, I get `(101279.0, 101279.0)
(98575.0, 98575.0)
(100288.0, 100288.0)
(94485.0, 94485.0)...` as output.

Comment: and `r_data` is `array([[ 110.,  107.,  126., ...,  134.,  129.,   47.],
       [ 171.,   25.,   30., ...,   37.,   50.,   53.],
       [  72.,   51.,   65., ...,  100.,   63.,  142.],
       ..., `